# How to access window SmallScroll method from Python

Tags: python, excel

I am new Python user and trying to get an Excel spreadsheet to scroll automatically in a loop as a video test.

Using VBA it seems that the SmallScroll method is an easy way to scroll Excel
Example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=3
```

I can create an Excel worksheet form Python( Tutorial on using VBA from Python)

```
import win32com.client

ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.visible = True

#This creates a new workbook
ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()

# Add a new sheet
Excelwkrsht = ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
```

However, if I try to access method

```
scroll1 = Excelwkrsht.SmallScroll(3)
```

I get an error.
Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you google for **Automate Tasks Python** you will find some material.

If you are trying to automate tasks with Excel, there is a module for that.

You can install the **openpyxl** Module.

There is a [full chapter here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) where you can find real nice info!

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you Andre, I appreciate your reply. I am aware of the openpyxl, and I did peruse the chapter you highlight. I am trying to create a test pattern to debug some artifacts. The content of the Excel is not as important as the motion of the Excel spreadsheet. I could not find anywhere from Google or Youtube( I only looked for a few hours), how to automatically move Excel except in the native windows VBA. I am trying to move Excel in Python with the SmallScroll method.